# Finding Corresponding Public SSH Key

Tags: ssh, public-key, authorized-keys

Lets say I've added a ssh public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  And I'm sshing into the machine from my client machine using `ssh -i <private_key> root@machine.ip.com`.  Is there a way to programmatically find the corresponding (accepting) public key to my ssh key from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` after the ssh?  I'm assuming I have multiple keys in authorized_keys.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can (ab)use the command option inside authorized_keys, e.g.:

```
command="echo key1; /bin/bash" ssh-rsa ...
```

You could also set an environment variable, e.g.:

```
command="KEY=key1 /bin/bash" ssh-rsa ...
```

Then when you ssh into, you will get:

```
-> % ssh user@host
key1
[user@host ~]$
```

Don't really know if this is the amount of programmatically you want.

Comment: Very neat, better than mine + 1

Answer (score 0):

`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` contains public keys, so all you need to do it match the public key of your private key.

You can generate the public key of the private key using:

```
openssl rsa -in <private_key> -pubout
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only 1 matching public key for your private key (otherwise PKI is broken).

Therefore you can simply just run

```
 ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/your_priv_key > your_pub_key
```